# Number of checked bags when travelling - domestic leg United and international leg by Jet Airways

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airlines

I am travelling from CVG-EWR-BOM-MAA and returning from MAA-BOM-EWR-SDF. I bought the tickets from Jet Airways (India). The domestic leg, CVG-EWR and EWR-SDF are on United Airlines (No code-share). I booked the ticket on Jan, 17, 2013. EWR-BOM-MAA is on Jet Airways (MSC). Since I bought the ticket from Jet Airways, they are the marketing carrier. So, which airline baggage policy would be applied? The above itinerary has the same PNR number issued on a single eticket.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Did you buy tickets together or separately?  From what I can tell they tickets were bought separately, so policies of both airlines will apply on their respective legs.

Comment: If there are no partner airlines involved, and the ticket was not sold as a whole by Jet airways, my experience says you will have different (respective) air lines luggage policy

Comment: Presuming the flights were all purchased on the same ticket/PNR (which it appears they were), then this is an exact duplicate of the question listed above.